# execution stops after web browser opens

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

```
webbrowser.get("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s").open('file://' + os.path.realpath('get.html'))
print('hello')
```

I have the code above in one of my python files. When I execute it, it opens 'get.html' just fine. However, the execution freezes at that point, the command prompt wont say 'hello' until I close the browser.

Can anyone explain how to fix this issue?

Comment: this is probably expected behavior.  Your program runs the first line until it gets an exit from the browser program.  You can work around this by creating a new process.using multiprocessing

Comment: I had a similar issue, but unfortunately never found a solid solution. The work around I used was simply to use another web browser/driver. For whatever reason, firefox works on my work pc, and chrome works at home. They bother run win7 and the same versions of python.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
import os
import webbrowser

url = "file://" + os.path.realpath("get.html")
browser_path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
#browser_path = "C:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe"

webbrowser.register("wb", None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(browser_path))
webbrowser.get("wb").open(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source for `webbrowser.get` i found that you can append `&` to make it a `BackgroundBrowser`:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.get("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s &").open("https://stackoverflow.com")
```

Now it doesn't hang and you can add other arguments such as [incognito](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42912975/1020871).

Tried on Windows, Python 3.8