# Opening a private window in your browser through python

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

I've found a way to open a tab using [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html#module-webbrowser) but that's not really what I'm looking for as it really needs to be a private window (a private tab is fine too).
:/ any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

For chrome, you can use

```
import os
os.system("chrome -incognito http://example.com")
```

depending on your OS, chrome may be installed under a different name such as `google-chrome` or `chrome-stable`

Answer (score 0):

For those who also came here and didn't find the answer, this helped me:

[how to open chrome in incognito mode from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37769148/how-to-open-chrome-in-incognito-mode-from-python)

```
import webbrowser
url = 'www.google.com'
chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s --incognito'
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open_new(url)
```

PS: Attention
The chrome path may be different on your computer.

PS2:
Please enter the link and credit the authors ([how to open chrome in incognito mode from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37769148/how-to-open-chrome-in-incognito-mode-from-python))