# Open Chrome Page in incognito mode from Python

Tags: python, html, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, incognito-mode

There are 2 subjects about this issue but all is not for mac.

How can i open a webpage in Incognito mode with Python in my Mac Computer ?

Normal is easy

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('http://example.com')  # Go to example.com
```

Some guys this a code like this but this is also now working for mac.

```
import webbrowser

url = 'http://docs.python.org/'

# MacOS
chrome_path = 'open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app %s'
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)
```

Any idea ?

Comment: There are several solutions here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37769148/how-to-open-chrome-in-incognito-mode-from-python have you confirmed that none work on mac?

Comment: @HymnsForDisco yes i have.

Comment: here are a few answers of commands that should work https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/306399/open-a-new-chrome-window-in-incognito-mode-from-terminal , you can execute them with the python subprocess module

Comment: I think, if i find chrome path for mac, i can do it, but i can't find it yet.

Comment: As usual, stack exchange seems to have more answers on this topic. I personally don't have a mac to test but check this out. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/95837/find-google-chrome-installation-directory-using-terminal

Comment: is not a easy answer like pc users ? like C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not a mac user so about the best I could do is google it for you.  Hopefully these links have given you the right direction

Comment: Thank you, i made google search, can't find, after i write here, regards

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are using mac OS looking at the patch of your chrome

I also struggled with this one. I ended up using os

```
import os

os.system("open -na \"Google Chrome\" --args --incognito \"www.google.com\"")
```