# Open an incognito window with Python's webbrowser module on MacOS

Tags: python, google-chrome, python-webbrowser, incognito-mode

Is there any way to open an incognito window in Chrome with the `webbrowser` module in MacOS? I'd like to be able to open a specific page in incognito mode. Something like `webbrowser.open_new('example.com --incognito')` would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to open chrome in incognito mode from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42912975/1305461)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that that my questions's for MacOS.